# Discord bot responds twice to two triggers in the same sentence

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So uh i just made my own discord bot a few days back i made some triggers [i dont know why but i call them triggers]

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'MYTOKENHERE';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    bot.user.setActivity(`YOU`, { type: 'WATCHING' });
    console.log('This bot is online!');   
})

bot.on('message', message=>{
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('bsdk')) {
        message.reply('This is a English only chat.');
        message.delete();
    };
})  

bot.on('message', message=>{
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('madarchod')) {
        message.reply('This is a English only chat.');
         message.delete();
    };
})

bot.login(token);
```

if i use both od the trigger words in the same sentence my bot reacts twice to them pls help me with a way to stop the bot from somehow doing it. THanks in advance.

Comment: I guess that you have run your bot twice the duplicate all the handle message come.
So provide more code related

Comment: Please add more code, to be able to see how these two pieces of code connects

Comment: okay ill add in more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using 2 separate `message` events, you can do everything in one;

```js
bot.on('message', message=>{
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('bsdk')) {
        message.reply('This is a English only chat.');
        message.delete();
    } else if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('madarchod')) {
        message.reply('This is a English only chat.');
         message.delete();
    }
})
```